# how to add another list parameter for meta_query

Tags: wordpress

here is my wordpress new query loop $args

```
if (isset($_GET['list_shows'])) {
    if ($_GET['list_shows'] == 'update') {
        $orderby = 'modified';
        $order = '';
    } elseif ($_GET['list_shows'] == 'views') {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
        $order = 'DESC';
    } elseif ($_GET['list_shows'] == 'popularity') {
        $orderby = 'comment_count';
        $order = 'DESC';
    }
} else {
    $orderby = 'modified';
    $order = '';
}
$argz=array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'orderby'=>$orderby,
    'order'=>$order,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
         'key' => 'fragman',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
         'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        )
    ),
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'after' => '2 days ago',
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    ),
);
```

the question is about ordering posts by meta_value_num , descending ?

my post views meta key = views, could we add this ordering parameter in this meta query ?

if it is, how can we do it. ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass like this

```
global $wp_query;
  $args = array(
        'meta_key' => 'views',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
query_posts( array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query ) );
```

I hope this will work for you.